# Fibonacci series gone wrong

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to print Fibonacci series in an file named "fibonacci.txt" up to 200 terms But after execution the file contained some wrong sums,

> some sums were less than expected

- I've checked that it's not any wrong data type, I've used unsigned long so there should not be any problem.
- I'm using Cfree 5.0.

I'm attaching the code and output with question.

```
int main(){
ofstream text_file;
text_file.open("fibonnacci.txt");

unsigned long sum, sum1=1, sum2=1;

text_file<<sum1<<"\t"<<sum2<<"\t";
for(int i = 1; i < 200; i++)    {
    sum = sum1 + sum2;
    text_file<<sum<<"\n";
    /*if(i%5 == 0){
        text_file<<"\n";
    }*/
    sum2 = sum1;
    sum1 = sum;

}
text_file<<"\n";

return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT

```
102334155
165580141
267914296
433494437
701408733
1134903170
1836311903
2971215073
512559680
3483774753
3996334433
3185141890
2886509027
1776683621
368225352
2144908973
2513134325
363076002
2876210327
3239286329
1820529360
764848393
2585377753
3350226146
```

These are some mid terms. Clearly we can see that some terms are less than the previous terms by calculating number of digits.

Comment: You need to read more about [integer types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Integer_types) and check [the range of the them](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Range_of_values).

Comment: I know that unsigned long data type has a high range of about 4 billion so there should not be any problem.

Comment: If you have 1.8 billion and add 2.9 billion, what would the result be? Well *over* the around 4 billion limit of unsigned 32-bit integers. And this is the problem you're having with adding e.g. `1836311903` and `2971215073` and getting `512559680`.

Comment: ok.. so just tried using double and it is working pretty well. but it gives answers in power of ten rounding off last digits. Is there any way to get precise number??

Comment: @GiteshwarMali of course there is a way to get the precise number - use a non-floating-point type of sufficient size (perhaps `unsigned long long`, though I can't recall OTTOMH if that's standard). If non exists on your platform, look into using a library which supports big numbers ("bignums").

Comment: can you suggest some libraries?

Comment: @GiteshwarMali Sure, let me google that for you... but seriously, off the top of my head, there's [GMP](https://gmplib.org/).

Comment: If you adjust the formatting of your insertion `<<` you should be able to display 10 digits without an issue.  Look at `iomanip`.

Comment: Thank's all for their suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a overrun in your sum variable. unsigned long has a maximum number of 4294967295. Try usings __int64 for example

Comment: ... which will also not get you much further. For 200 terms, double should be Ok.

Comment: @gnasher729 double worked. thanks... I thought that unsigned long would be sufficient. But double gives answer in power of ten and rounds off digits can't I get precise numbers?